# « Zoprack » L'emploi du verlan et les noms de marques

Tags: argot, noms-propres, paroles-de-chanson, lexique, verlan

Dans la chanson *L'instant X* par Mylène Farmer, le mot *zoprack* m'intéresse au niveau de la productivité de la langue et l'argot.  Les paroles :

> Papa Noël quand tu descendras du ciel 
> Du fun, du ***zoprack*** et des ailes

J'ai toujours pensé que c'était simplement le verlan de *prozac* et donc assez ordinaire, puis je me demande s'il y a d'autres noms propres ou plutôt des noms de marques (lexicalisés ou pas) qui ont subis une telle transformation du verlan.  Pour inventer un exemple, de Bic à *kib, genre.

Donc j'ai fait un peu de recherche et j'ai trouvé que l'usage  n'est pas fréquent dans le cas de *zoprack* (aucun résultat Ngrams et environ 6 000 résultats Google dont la plupart cite la chanson).  Selon un [entretien](https://www.mylene.net/mylene/d_s_linstantx_histoire.php) avec Farmer, c'est elle qui l'a créé pour sa chanson.

> "Zoprack  : j'ai été obligée. Prozac, c'est interdit. On n'a pas le droit de faire la publicité d'un médicament. Donc, plutôt que de l'enlever et de le tuer, j'ai préféré le mutiler et m’en amuser." (NRJ - 16/10/1995)

Il me paraît que *zoprack* suit les « règles » du verlan (ou pas, bien noté par @jlliagre) et la musique n'est pas inconnue, mais ça ne finit pas par se lexicaliser, ce qui n'est pas si exceptionnel pour l'argot. J'ai trouvé *gromi* pour  Migros, le supermarché suisse.  Il est bien possible que j'ignore des noms de marques comme le français n'est pas ma langue maternelle.  De plus, ce sont des mots qui conviennent aux diverses générations et qui tendent à évoluer *a priori*.

Question : Est-ce qu'il y a d'autres exemples du verlan des noms de marque (génériques, antonomases ou propres) qui font partie du vocabulaire plus répandu ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Zoprack* ne suit par de manière stricte les « règles » du verlan  puisque  *Prozac* devrait donner *zacpro*.

Un nom de marque assez courant qui lui aussi ne respecte pas les règles habituelles du verlan est *carrouf* pour *Carrefour* :

[image]

On trouve aussi *costla* pour *Lacoste*.

Comment: carrouf : carr-ouf → carr[ément]-fou

Comment: J'adore, cimer !  Je viens de trouver *gromi* pour la Migros en Suisse ; tu m'inspires.

Comment: Pour rester dans le même domaine, une chaîne de supérettes bien connue dans les stations de ski françaises: *Sherpa* ;-)

Comment: Étape par étape, ça coûte combien ? : )

Comment: Le prix d'une lexro !

Comment: Ou pas-cher ?  J'hésite.